# How to know which nadi is triggered at present?

Tags: yoga

The human psychic body has two types of nadis which as I know are Surya nadi and Chandra nadi. 
AFAIK, the nadis change automatically but one can also trigger them as needed. How to know which nadi is triggered at present and how to change it to other nadi?

Comment: You are right. The nadis can be triggered as required and it is simple. Lie on a flat, hard bed on your side. You should lie on the side corresponding to the closed nostril, and within a few minutes it will open up. I have personally tried this many times.

Comment: When Surya (Pingala Nadhi) is more active, breath will be more prominent within right nostril. When Chandra (Ida Nadhi) is more active, the left nostril will be more active. You can pay atention to which nostril is breathing more along the day, just by closing one or the other and watch which side is more easy to breath. You will notice diferente time to time. And some times both are similar, that is Sushumna Nadhi more prominent (very good time for spiritual practices). Another way to know, is to breath by nose very close on a mirror (or glass), and watch which halo is bigger (rigth or left)

Comment: On every one of these 3 (Surya, Chandra or Sushumna) there are activities you can perform, and others you shouldn't (study maths on Surya, paint on Chandra, don't cuarrel on Sushumna, etc). Every human activity can be putted on this 3 matches. So, is not good idea to change it, without knowing what are you doing. Better to repeat God's name and let everything happen by itself. There are technichs (Bedhanas, Sodhanas) to change it. BUT TAKE CARE, never to perform deep kumbhaka. Find a real guru!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is a question related to physical practice, an actual teacher can best describe it. But I am providing a brief information so that it will be helpful.

There are actually many *nadis*, but three are important. Two you have already mentioned, the Surya *nadi* and Chandra *nadi*. They are also called as *pingala* and *ida* respectively. The third one is *Sushanma* (roughly the spinal chord). You can know which of the two *nadis* is active by this simple method:

- Put your fingers under your nostril and exhaust air out of your nose so that you can feel it on your fingers.
- You'll find that air from one nostril is coming in more quantity.
- If the nostril is the right one, then Surya *nadi* is active and if the nostril is the left one, then Chandra *nadi* is active.

The rhythm changes throughout day from nostril to nostril and also sometimes both the nostrils are active. Regarding triggering them automatically, it's not easy. You have to practice yoga techniques like *pranayama*. If you can change or trigger the flow of air at will then you have already perfected *pranayama* which takes years of practice.