# What is the difference between Surya nadi and Chandra nadi?

Tags: yoga

This question is extend of my [previous question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/766/93). There are beliefs that some works should be done only when we have Surya nadi and other works should be done in Chandra nadi.

Is the specific works related to Nadis mentioned somewhere in scriptures? please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information about breathing science is contained in **Swarodhaya Shastra**. It is also referred to as *Shiva Swarodaya* and *Phonetical astrology* <sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Swarodaya_/_Swara_Yoga)</sup>. Though I have never read the scripture myself, I am quoting from my friend's notes on Swarodhaya Shastra. It was incomplete and so I could give only a limited answer.

When the breath flows through the right nostril, it is called *Surya Swara* (or surya nadi) and when it flows through the left nostril, it is called *Chandra Swara* (or chandra nadi). The process by which the flow changes from one nostril to the other is called *Swara Sankranti*. Rarely, the breath may flow through both the nostrils, which is termed as *Vishvat Kala*.

The *Surya Swara* represents *male energy* and the *Chandra Swara* represents *female energy*. So, the power of breath for a man is highest in the Surya Swara and for a female, it is highest in the Chandra Swara.